# Multiple errors in OpenCV Face Detection sample

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I start using OpenCV library for Android and want to build the examples supplied with the OpenCV sdk library for Android. In particular, I build "Face Detection" OpenCV sample.

While the project itself builds fine, in Eclipse I see the following error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Symbol 'NULL' could not be resolved
    - Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: const char * GetStringUTFChars(_jstring *, unsigned char *) '
```

in the following string of the file `jni/DetectionBasedTracker_jni.cpp`:

```
const char* jnamestr = jenv->GetStringUTFChars(jFileName, NULL);
```

I already added all necessary paths but I still see this error. Any suggestions?

Comment: The easiest solution is to replace `NULL` with `0`.

Comment: I already tried to define NULL as 0, however, the second error does not disappear. I'm leaving it here because, maybe, it is related with the second one.

Comment: No, just put `0` as the argument instead of NULL.

Comment: `I already added all necessary paths but I still see this error. Any suggestions?`  Also, NULL is not a built-in constant in C++.  Did you `#include` the proper header file that defines NULL? `<cstddef>`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie putting 0 as an argument instead NULL solves the problem. However, I do not understand why I receive this error. I build the sample and I suppose that it should work if I have followed all the steps in the tutorial. Should I submit a bug to OpenCV developers?

Comment: Did you `#include <cstddef>`?  Again, `NULL` is not a built-in constant.  It is defined in a header file, and that header should be `<cstddef>`.  Also, many tutorials assume you're #including the appropriate header files.  It may not be the most user-friendly way to introduce a concept, but sometimes you have to fill in those gaps yourself.

Comment: As I said the problem is not with the compiler (the .so library is built without errors) but with Eclipse itself. I tried to include <cstddef> but no effect. In the project configuration there is an entry that points to the folder with necessary header files. However, could you please, write an answer so I can accept it?